# DIfference between PaintEventArgs.Graphics and Graphics.FromHwnd in Drawing

Tags: c#, winforms, draw, picturebox

### Latest

```
//combination of pictureBox1.Invalidate(); and pictureBox1.Update();
pictureBox1.Refresh();
```

After `pictureBox1.Refresh();` , it will trigger `pictureBox1_Paint`

Following code will have the icon remain on the picture box.

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawIcon(IconCamera, rect);
    }
}
```

Following code NOT! it will draw the icon and **clear** it soon after it was drawn in Paint (that why have my old question)

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromHwnd(pictureBox1.Handle);
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        graphic.DrawIcon(IconCamera, rect);
    }
}
```

I thought these two graphics are same but it seem like they are not same.

1. May I know what is the difference of `Graphics` of PaintEventArgs of
   pictureBox1 and  `Graphics` from handle of pictureBox1?
2. Why `DrawIcon` on pictureBox1 Paint event with `Graphics` from handle of
   pictureBox1 will **disappear** in Paint event but **not** in the function I
   **declared**? thanks

---

### Old Question

When I checked the checkbox then I will draw icon on the picture box,

```
Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromHwnd(pictureBox1.Handle);
if (checkBox1.CheckState.ToString() == "Checked")
{
    Icon IconCamera = new Icon("cam.ico");
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100, 32, 32);
    graphic.DrawIcon(IconCamera, rect);
}
```

BUT After the picture box refresh,

```
pictureBox1.Refresh();
```

the drawn icon will **disappear**.

May I know what picturebox **event** OR else can I make use to put in the drawing icon code to **maintain** or always **auto redraw** the icon even after the picture box `refresh()?` thanks. I tried `Paint` and `Validating` of picturebox1 cannot work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best is to use two calls one after each other:

```
pictureBox1.Invalidate();
pictureBox1.Update();
```

This will force the picturebox to be redrawn.

Then I subscribe for `Paint` event, which is signalled when previous two lines of code are called (in case of redrawing the picturebox).  Here I do the all the drawings.

In your case it would be something like this:

```
public void Paint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100, 32, 32);
        Icon IconCamera = new Icon("cam.ico");
        e.Graphics.DrawIcon(IconCamera, rect);
    }
}
```

Then, subscribe for event `CheckedChanged` of `checkBox1`, and call there that two redrawing commands from the begin of this post.

It causes, that when user change the checked state of `checkBox1`, `pictureBox1` will be forced to be redrawn and the icon will be drawn according to `checkBox1` state.

Comment: you mean after refresh? actually I need to put my drawing icon to a event that will always trigger after I refresh the picturebox. thanks

Comment: I mean to call this at the end of code which changes the picturebox. It will force it to redraw.

Comment: where should I put the redraw code? we have redraw picturebox event? thanks

Comment: Now it is complete. If it is not clear, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Hans Passant: I don't think so. Invalidate does not paint in immediately, it only add it to something like "TODO list". From MSDN: Calling the Invalidate method does not force a synchronous paint; to force a synchronous paint, call the Update method after calling the Invalidate method. When this method is called with no parameters, the entire client area is added to the update region.

Comment: thank for your answer and finally I found my error is assume pictureBox1 handle `Graphics` is same with painteventargs `Graphics` but actually not.

Comment: thanks for the `checkBox1.Checked` flag also, I never know I can check like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using a `Graphics` object and find another way. I don't know if you are forced in using an icon, but you can try to use a `Label` this way.

```
label1.Image = "yourImage.bmp" // you can use a bitmap
```

There here come your statement.

```
if(checkBox1.Checked) {
   label1.Visible = true;
   label1.Location = new Point(x, y); // your coordinate 
}
```

Then you can handle `checkBox1_CheckedChanged` and code:

```
Void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if(!checkBox1.Checked) {
    label1.Visible = false;
  }
}
```

Hope this could help.

Comment: I can draw multiple icon in one picture,and your method is load some sort of background image to label,not my answer